# List<T> and IEnumerable difference

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

While implementing this generic [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), as a kind of [Code Kata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_%28programming%29), I stumbled on a difference between IEnumerable and List that I need help to figure out.

Here's the MergeSort

```
public class MergeSort<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> arr)
    {
        if (arr.Count() <= 1) return arr;

        int middle = arr.Count() / 2;
        var left = arr.Take(middle).ToList();
        var right = arr.Skip(middle).ToList();
        return Merge(Sort(left), Sort(right));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> Merge(IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
    {
        var arrSorted = new List<T>();

        while (left.Count() > 0 && right.Count() > 0)
        {
            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(left.First(), right.First()) < 0)
            {
                arrSorted.Add(left.First());
                left=left.Skip(1);
            }
            else
            {
                arrSorted.Add(right.First());  
                right=right.Skip(1);  
            }
        }

        return arrSorted.Concat(left).Concat(right);
    }
}
```

If I remove the `.ToList()` on the `left` and `right` variables it fails to sort correctly. Do you see why?

Example

```
var ints = new List<int> { 5, 8, 2, 1, 7 };
var mergeSortInt = new MergeSort<int>();
var sortedInts = mergeSortInt.Sort(ints);
```

With `.ToList()`

```
    [0]: 1
    [1]: 2
    [2]: 5
    [3]: 7
    [4]: 8
```

Without `.ToList()`

```
    [0]: 1
    [1]: 2
    [2]: 5
    [3]: 7
    [4]: 2
```

**Edit**

It was my stupid test that got me.

I tested it like this:

```
var sortedInts = mergeSortInt.Sort(ints);
ints.Sort();
if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ints, sortedInts)) Console.WriteLine("ints sorts ok");
```

just changing the first row to

```
var sortedInts = mergeSortInt.Sort(ints).ToList();
```

removes the problem (and the lazy evaluation).

**EDIT 2010-12-29**

I thought I would figure out just how the lazy evaluation messes things up here but I just don't get it.

Remove the `.ToList()` in the Sort method above like this

```
var left = arr.Take(middle);
var right = arr.Skip(middle);
```

then try this

```
var ints = new List<int> { 5, 8, 2 };
var mergeSortInt = new MergeSort<int>();
var sortedInts = mergeSortInt.Sort(ints);
ints.Sort();
if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(ints, sortedInts)) Console.WriteLine("ints sorts ok");
```

When debugging You can see that before `ints.Sort()` a `sortedInts.ToList()` returns

```
[0]: 2
[1]: 5
[2]: 8
```

but after `ints.Sort()` it returns

```
[0]: 2
[1]: 5
[2]: 5
```

What is really happening here?

Comment: Must say that it worked well on my PC after removing `ToList()`

Comment: Here's another fail-to-reproduce example (using mono): http://ideone.com/7mllZ

Comment: The only suspicious part I see is `left=left.Skip(1)`, which might have problems with delayed execution, but I can't see how.

Comment: I added a new example to the question because I still couldn't figure out exactly what's happening here.

Comment: I've implemented a fully lazy evaluated version http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2011/01/01/lazy-evaluation-is-no-friend-of-mutable-state

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function is correct - if you inspect the result of `Merge`, you'll see the result is sorted [(example)](http://ideone.com/NirvK).
So where's the problem? Just as you've suspected, you're testing it wrong - **when you call `Sort` on your original list you change all collections that derive from it!**
Here's a snippet that demonstrates what you did:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> {5, 4};
IEnumerable<int> first = numbers.Take(1);
Console.WriteLine(first.Single()); //prints 5
numbers.Sort();
Console.WriteLine(first.Single()); //prints 4!
```

All collections you create are basically the same as `first` - in a way, they are lazy pointers to positions in `ints`. Obviously, when you call `ToList`, the problem is eliminated.

Your case is more complex than that. Your `Sort` is part lazy, exactly as you suggest: First you create a list (`arrSorted`) and add integers to it. That part isn't lazy, and is the reason you see the first few elements sorted. Next, you add the remaining elements - but `Concat` is lazy. Now, recursion enters to mess this even more: In most cases, most elements on your `IEnumerable` are eager - you create lists out of left and right, which are also made of mostly eager + lazy tail. You end up with a sorted `List<int>`, lazily concated to a lazy pointer, which should be *just the last element* (other elements were merged before).
Here's a call graph of your functions - red indicated a lazy collection, black a real number:

> [image]

When you change the list the new list is mostly intact, but the last element is lazy, and point to the position of the largest element in the original list.

The result is mostly good, but its last element still points to the original list:

> [image]

One last example: consider you're changing all elements in the original list. As you can see, most elements in the sorted collection remain the same, but the last is lazy and points to the new value:

```
var ints = new List<int> { 3,2,1 };
var mergeSortInt = new MergeSort<int>();
var sortedInts = mergeSortInt.Sort(ints);
// sortedInts is { 1, 2, 3 }
for(int i=0;i<ints.Count;i++) ints[i] = -i * 10;
// sortedInts is { 1, 2, 0 }
```

Here's the same example on Ideone: http://ideone.com/FQVR7

Comment: I get that. I also get that mutable collections and lazy evaluation is a terrible mix. What I don't get is how it messes up the sort in this case because an already sorted list shouldn't be a problem. Unless my little MergeSort isn't totally lazy but just half lazy or something.

Comment: @Jonas - I've updated my explanation with more details, it seems there's more than a little complexity in your code `:)`

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Now I finally get it. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented a fully lazy evaluated version and blogged about it and the problems I faced. http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2011/01/01/lazy-evaluation-is-no-friend-of-mutable-state

Comment: @Jonas - Thanks for all the attention, happy to help!

Answer (score 6):

Unable to reproduce - I've just tried this, and it works absolutely fine. Obviously it's rather inefficient in various ways, but removing the `ToList` calls didn't make it fail.

Here's my test code, with your `MergeSort` code as-is, but without the `ToList()` calls:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Dump<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        var ints = new List<int> { 5, 8, 2, 1, 7 };
        var mergeSortInt = new MergeSort<int>();
        var sortedInts = mergeSortInt.Sort(ints);
        sortedInts.Dump("Sorted");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sorted
1 2 5 7 8
```

Perhaps the problem was how you were testing your code?

Comment: I thought I would figure out just how the lazy evaluation messes things up here but I just don't get it. I added a new example to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I ran it with and without the list and it worked.
Anyway, one of the strengths points of merge sort is its ability to sort in-place with O(1) space complexity that this implementation will not benefit.

Comment: Merge sort doesn't claim to be O(1) complexity. It's O(n log n).

Comment: It doesn't claim to, but it can be implemented in O(1) space complexity and a small constant factor for the O(nlgn) time complexity which are both lack here.

Comment: Ah, do you mean *space* complexity? I've never heard of "place complexity" before. If so, yes, that's true. This is inefficient in a number of ways, but I assume it's for educational experimentation, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you sort the left right, than the right side and merge to one sequence. That does not mean that you get a completely sorted sequence.

First you have to merge and than you have to sort:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Sort(IEnumerable<T> arr)
{
    if (arr.Count() <= 1) return arr;

    int middle = arr.Count() / 2;
    var left = arr.Take(middle).ToList();
    var right = arr.Skip(middle).ToList();

    // first merge and than sort
    return Sort(Merge(left, right));
}
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of merge sort - you might as well `Sort(arr)` - you suggest to split and merge (= do nothing), and then sort `:)`