# Why are Java Streams once-off?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, api-design

Unlike C#'s `IEnumerable`, where an execution pipeline can be executed as many times as we want, in Java a stream can be 'iterated' only once.

Any call to a terminal operation closes the stream, rendering it unusable.
This 'feature' takes away a lot of power.

I imagine the reason for this is *not* technical. What were the design considerations behind this strange restriction?

Edit: in order to demonstrate what I am talking about, consider the following implementation of Quick-Sort in C#:

```
IEnumerable<int> QuickSort(IEnumerable<int> ints)
{
  if (!ints.Any()) {
    return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
  }

  int pivot = ints.First();

  IEnumerable<int> lt = ints.Where(i => i < pivot);
  IEnumerable<int> gt = ints.Where(i => i > pivot);

  return QuickSort(lt).Concat(new int[] { pivot }).Concat(QuickSort(gt));
}
```

Now to be sure, I am not advocating that this is a good implementation of quick sort! It is however great example of the expressive power of lambda expression combined with stream operation.

And it can't be done in Java!
I can't even ask a stream whether it is empty without rendering it unusable.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example where closing the stream "takes away power"?

Comment: If you want to use data from a stream more than once, you'll have to dump it out into a collection.  This is pretty much how it _has_ to work: either you have to redo the computation to generate the stream, or you have to store the intermediate result.

Comment: Ok, but redoing the *same* computation on the *same* stream sounds wrong. A stream is created from a given source before a computation is performed, just like iterators are created for each iteration. I would still like to see an actual concrete example; in the end, I bet there is a clean way to solve each problem with use-once streams, assuming a corresponding way exists with C#'s enumerables.

Comment: This was confusing at first to me, because i thought this question would relate C#s `IEnumerable` to the streams of `java.io.*`

Comment: A related but not duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38518/3474

Comment: If you want reusable java 8 stream check out https://github.com/kishorenayar/Reusable-Java8-Streams

Comment: Note that using IEnumerable multiple times in C# is a fragile pattern, so the premise of the question may be slightly flawed. Many implementations of IEnumerable do allow it but some do not! Code analysis tools tend to warn you against doing such a thing.

Comment: I disagree with the "fragile pattern" comment. The code analyzers warn you based on the assumption that evaluating the Enumerable from scratch is expensive (not always true), and that collecting the values is cheap (not always true - if ints is a sequence of all integers, .ToList() is a mistake). It mostly comes from the assumption that the Enumerable is wrapping SQL, so you'd execute the same SQL multiple times without realizing. Linq over SQL is a minority of Linq usage.

Comment: Comparing C#’s `IEnumerable` and Java Streams is apples to oranges. A more appropriate comparison would be to some .Net `Stream` implementations.

Comment: @KishoreKarunakaran they are not reusable anymore. Link is broken

Answer (score 387, accepted):

I have some recollections from the early design of the Streams API that might shed some light on the design rationale.

Back in 2012, we were adding lambdas to the language, and we wanted a collections-oriented or "bulk data" set of operations, programmed using lambdas, that would facilitate parallelism. The idea of lazily chaining operations together was well established by this point. We also didn't want the intermediate operations to store results.

The main issues we needed to decide were what the objects in the chain looked like in the API and how they hooked up to data sources. The sources were often collections, but we also wanted to support data coming from a file or the network, or data generated on-the-fly, e.g., from a random number generator.

There were many influences of existing work on the design. Among the more influential were Google's [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library and the Scala collections library. (If anybody is surprised about the influence from Guava, note that [Kevin Bourrillion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202214/kevin-bourrillion), Guava lead developer, was on the [JSR-335 Lambda](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335) expert group.) On Scala collections, we found this talk by Martin Odersky to be of particular interest: [Future-Proofing Scala Collections: from Mutable to Persistent to Parallel](http://youtu.be/HoIOIluNFzQ). (Stanford EE380, 2011 June 1.)

Our prototype design at the time was based around `Iterable`. The familiar operations `filter`, `map`, and so forth were extension (default) methods on `Iterable`. Calling one added an operation to the chain and returned another `Iterable`. A terminal operation like `count` would call `iterator()` up the chain to the source, and the operations were implemented within each stage's Iterator.

Since these are Iterables, you can call the `iterator()` method more than once. What should happen then?

If the source is a collection, this mostly works fine. Collections are Iterable, and each call to `iterator()` produces a distinct Iterator instance that is independent of any other active instances, and each traverses the collection independently. Great.

Now what if the source is one-shot, like reading lines from a file? Maybe the first Iterator should get all the values but the second and subsequent ones should be empty. Maybe the values should be interleaved among the Iterators. Or maybe each Iterator should get all the same values. Then, what if you have two iterators and one gets farther ahead of the other? Somebody will have to buffer up the values in the second Iterator until they're read. Worse, what if you get one Iterator and read all the values, and only *then* get a second Iterator. Where do the values come from now? Is there a requirement for them all to be buffered up *just in case* somebody wants a second Iterator?

Clearly, allowing multiple Iterators over a one-shot source raises a lot of questions. We didn't have good answers for them. We wanted consistent, predictable behavior for what happens if you call `iterator()` twice. This pushed us toward disallowing multiple traversals, making the pipelines one-shot.

We also observed others bumping into these issues. In the JDK, most Iterables are collections or collection-like objects, which allow multiple traversal. It isn't specified anywhere, but there seemed to be an unwritten expectation that Iterables allow multiple traversal. A notable exception is the NIO [DirectoryStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) interface. Its specification includes this interesting warning:

> **While DirectoryStream extends Iterable, it is not a general-purpose Iterable as it supports only a single Iterator; invoking the iterator method to obtain a second or subsequent iterator throws IllegalStateException.**

[bold in original]

This seemed unusual and unpleasant enough that we didn't want to create a whole bunch of new Iterables that might be once-only. This pushed us away from using Iterable.

About this time, an [article by Bruce Eckel](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=339521) appeared that described a spot of trouble he'd had with Scala. He'd written this code:

```
// Scala
val lines = fromString(data).getLines
val registrants = lines.map(Registrant)
registrants.foreach(println)
registrants.foreach(println)
```

It's pretty straightforward. It parses lines of text into `Registrant` objects and prints them out twice. Except that it actually only prints them out once. It turns out that he thought that `registrants` was a collection, when in fact it's an iterator. The second call to `foreach` encounters an empty iterator, from which all values have been exhausted, so it prints nothing.

This kind of experience convinced us that it was very important to have clearly predictable results if multiple traversal is attempted. It also highlighted the importance of distinguishing between lazy pipeline-like structures from actual collections that store data. This in turn drove the separation of the lazy pipeline operations into the new Stream interface and keeping only eager, mutative operations directly on Collections. [Brian Goetz has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24472635/1441122) the rationale for that.

What about allowing multiple traversal for collection-based pipelines but disallowing it for non-collection-based pipelines? It's inconsistent, but it's sensible. If you're reading values from the network, *of course* you can't traverse them again. If you want to traverse them multiple times, you have to pull them into a collection explicitly.

But let's explore allowing multiple traversal from collections-based pipelines. Let's say you did this:

```
Iterable<?> it = source.filter(...).map(...).filter(...).map(...);
it.into(dest1);
it.into(dest2);
```

(The `into` operation is now spelled `collect(toList())`.)

If source is a collection, then the first `into()` call will create a chain of Iterators back to the source, execute the pipeline operations, and send the results into the destination. The second call to `into()` will create another chain of Iterators, and execute the pipeline operations **again**. This isn't obviously wrong but it does have the effect of performing all the filter and map operations a second time for each element. I think many programmers would have been surprised by this behavior.

As I mentioned above, we had been talking to the Guava developers. One of the cool things they have is an [Idea Graveyard](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IdeaGraveyard) where they describe features that they decided **not** to implement along with the reasons. The idea of lazy collections sounds pretty cool, but here's what they have to say about it. Consider a `List.filter()` operation that returns a `List`:

> The biggest concern here is that too many operations become expensive, linear-time propositions. If you want to filter a list and get a list back, and not just a Collection or an Iterable, you can use `ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.filter(list, predicate))`, which "states up front" what it's doing and how expensive it is.

To take a specific example, what's the cost of `get(0)` or `size()` on a List? For commonly used classes like `ArrayList`, they're O(1). But if you call one of these on a lazily-filtered list, it has to run the filter over the backing list, and all of a sudden these operations are O(n). Worse, it has to traverse the backing list on **every** operation.

This seemed to us to be *too much* laziness. It's one thing to set up some operations and defer actual execution until you so "Go". It's another to set things up in such a way that hides a potentially large amount of recomputation.

In proposing to disallow non-linear or "no-reuse" streams, [Paul Sandoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4042945/paul-sandoz) described the [potential consequences](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2012-November/000412.html) of allowing them as giving rise to "unexpected or confusing results." He also mentioned that parallel execution would make things even trickier. Finally, I'd add that a pipeline operation with side effects would lead to difficult and obscure bugs if the operation were unexpectedly executed multiple times, or at least a different number of times than the programmer expected. (But Java programmers don't write lambda expressions with side effects, do they? DO THEY??)

So that's the basic rationale for the Java 8 Streams API design that allows one-shot traversal and that requires a strictly linear (no branching) pipeline. It provides consistent behavior across multiple different stream sources, it clearly separates lazy from eager operations, and it provides a straightforward execution model.

---

With regard to `IEnumerable`, I am far from an expert on C# and .NET, so I would appreciate being corrected (gently) if I draw any incorrect conclusions. It does appear, however, that `IEnumerable` permits multiple traversal to behave differently with different sources; and it permits a branching structure of nested `IEnumerable` operations, which may result in some significant recomputation. While I appreciate that different systems make different tradeoffs, these are two characteristics that we sought to avoid in the design of the Java 8 Streams API.

The quicksort example given by the OP is interesting, puzzling, and I'm sorry to say, somewhat horrifying. Calling `QuickSort` takes an `IEnumerable` and returns an `IEnumerable`, so no sorting is actually done until the final `IEnumerable` is traversed. What the call seems to do, though, is build up a tree structure of `IEnumerables` that reflects the partitioning that quicksort would do, without actually doing it. (This is lazy computation, after all.) If the source has N elements, the tree will be N elements wide at its widest, and it will be lg(N) levels deep.

It seems to me -- and once again, I'm not a C# or .NET expert -- that this will cause certain innocuous-looking calls, such as pivot selection via `ints.First()`, to be more expensive than they look. At the first level, of course, it's O(1). But consider a partition deep in the tree, at the right-hand edge. To compute the first element of this partition, the entire source has to be traversed, an O(N) operation. But since the partitions above are lazy, they must be recomputed, requiring O(lg N) comparisons. So selecting the pivot would be an O(N lg N) operation, which is as expensive as an entire sort.

But we don't actually sort until we traverse the returned `IEnumerable`. In the standard quicksort algorithm, each level of partitioning doubles the number of partitions. Each partition is only half the size, so each level remains at O(N) complexity. The tree of partitions is O(lg N) high, so the total work is O(N lg N).

With the tree of lazy IEnumerables, at the bottom of the tree there are N partitions. Computing each partition requires a traversal of N elements, each of which requires lg(N) comparisons up the tree. To compute all the partitions at the bottom of the tree, then, requires O(N^2 lg N) comparisons.

(Is this right? I can hardly believe this. Somebody please check this for me.)

In any case, it is indeed cool that `IEnumerable` can be used this way to build up complicated structures of computation. But if it does increase the computational complexity as much as I think it does, it would seem that programming this way is something that should be avoided unless one is extremely careful.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the great and non-condescending answer! This is by far the most accurate and to the point explanation I got.
As far as the QuickSort example goes, It seems that you are right about ints.First bloating as the recursion level grow. I believe this can be easily fixed by computing 'gt' and 'lt' eagerly (by collecting the results with ToArray). That being said, it certainly supports your point that this style of programming may incur unexpected performance price. 

(Continue in second comment)

Comment: On the other hand, from my experience with C# (more that 5 years) I can tell that rooting out the 'redundant' computations is not that hard once you hit a performance issue (or got forbid, If someone made the unthinkable and introduced a side affect there). It just seemed to me that too much compromise was made to ensure the pureness of the API, at the expense of C# like possibilities. You've definitely helped me adjust my point of view.

Comment: @Vitaliy Thanks for the fair-minded exchange of ideas. I learned a little about C# and .NET from investigating and writing this answer.

Comment: Small comment: ReSharper is a Visual Studio extension that helps with C#. With the above QuickSort code ReSharper adds a warning **for each use `ints`**: "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable". Using the same `IEenumerable` more than once is suspicious and should be avoided. I'd also point to this question (which I've answered), which shows some of the caveats with the .Net approach (besides poor performance): [List<T> and IEnumerable difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4545090/7586)

Comment: @Kobi Very interesting that there is such a warning in ReSharper. Thanks for the pointer to your answer. I don't know C#/.NET so I'll have to pick through it carefully, but it does seem to exhibit issues similar to the design concerns I mentioned above.

Comment: generally speaking, unless the enumeration represented is pure and trivial, if you need to traverse it multiple times, you are expected and recommended to collapse it into a concrete collection using ToList or ToArray or something similar. It's not really the case that you can't enumerate it twice, but you are warned that doing this might have side effects, so you should use caution.

Comment: I would hope there was some pushback in the early discussions against the idea of making a `Stream` from data coming from the network or file system? After all, I don't see any checked exceptions thrown from `Stream` methods, so `IOException`s would have to be either swallowed, wrapped in
 `RuntimeExceptions`, or the creator of the `Stream` would have to provide an exception handler.

Comment: Also, random number generators are perfectly restartable, as long as they have state that can be cloned, rather than reading cosmic background radiation or something.

Comment: The nested IEnumerables in cases like this do get pretty nasty, but the number of times I've come across them is very low. It seems to me that Java's behaviour forces the developer to .collect their streams early and often in order to share them. This is sometimes desired/necessary for perf/correctness in C#, but more often that's not the case. Collecting early and re-streaming, collecting again, etc becomes inefficient. At least C# gives you the choice, but it's still a pain point where it's misunderstood. Sharing streams is something I do a lot and it's frustrating to not have that option.

Comment: @StuartMarks - Your answer well explains why we can't silently branch part-way through a Stream, but I don't understand why there's no syntax to explicitly declare the start of a branch, i.e. "execute up to here and cache results". Right now we're forced to write `.collect(toList())` then `.stream()` (a couple of times). Why not just have a syntax `.commit()` that performs all the actions up the that point and returns the result as a new source that implements Stream (ready for multiple downstream branches).

Comment: Note: You wouldn't want to call `.commit()` on an infinite stream (in exactly the same way you don't want to call `.collect()` on an infinite stream). Perhaps the syntax should be `.intermediateCollect`, `.collectForBranch()`, or `.executeToHere()`.

Answer (score 126):

## Background

While the question appears simple, the actual answer requires some background to make sense. If you want to skip to the conclusion, scroll down...

### Pick your comparison point - Basic functionality

Using basic concepts, C#'s `IEnumerable` concept is more closely related to [Java's `Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which is able to create as many [Iterators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) as you want. [`IEnumerables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IEnumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) create [`IEnumerators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx). Java's `Iterable` create `Iterators`

The history of each concept is similar, in that both `IEnumerable` and `Iterable` have a basic motivation to allow 'for-each' style looping over the members of data collections. That's an oversimplification as they both allow more than just that, and they also arrived at that stage via different progressions, but it is a significant common feature regardless.

Let's compare that feature: in both languages, if a class implements the `IEnumerable`/`Iterable`, then that class must implement at least a single method (for C#, it's `GetEnumerator` and for Java it's `iterator()`). In each case, the instance returned from that (`IEnumerator`/`Iterator`) allows you to access the current and subsequent members of the data. This feature is used in the for-each language syntax.

### Pick your comparison point - Enhanced functionality

`IEnumerable` in C# has been extended to allow a number of other language features ([mostly related to Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx)). Features added include selections, projections, aggregations, etc. These extensions have a strong motivation from use in set-theory, similar to SQL and Relational Database concepts.

Java 8 has also had functionality added to enable a degree of functional programming using Streams and Lambdas. Note that Java 8 streams are not primarily motivated by set theory, but by functional programming. Regardless, there are a lot of parallels.

So, this is the second point. The enhancements made to C# were implemented as an enhancement to the `IEnumerable` concept. In Java, though, the enhancements made were implemented by creating new base concepts of Lambdas and Streams, and then also creating a relatively trivial way to convert from `Iterators` and `Iterables` to Streams, and visa-versa.

So, comparing IEnumerable to Java's Stream concept is incomplete. You need to compare it to the combined Streams and Collections API's in Java.

### In Java, Streams are not the same as Iterables, or Iterators

Streams are not designed to solve problems the same way that iterators are:

- Iterators are a way of describing the sequence of data.
- Streams are a way of describing a sequence of data transformations.

With an `Iterator`, you get a data value, process it, and then get another data value.

With Streams, you chain a sequence of functions together, then you feed an input value to the stream, and get the output value from the combined sequence. Note, in Java terms, each function is encapsulated in a single `Stream` instance. The Streams API allows you to link a sequence of `Stream` instances in a way that chains a sequence of transformation expressions.

In order to complete the `Stream` concept, you need a source of data to feed the stream, and a terminal function that consumes the stream.

The way you feed values in to the stream may in fact be from an `Iterable`, but the `Stream` sequence itself is not an `Iterable`, it is a compound function.

A `Stream` is also intended to be lazy, in the sense that it only does work when you request a value from it.

Note these significant assumptions and features of Streams:

- A `Stream` in Java is a transformation engine, it transforms a data item in one state, to being in another state.
- streams have no concept of the data order or position, the simply transform whatever they are asked to.
- streams can be supplied with data from many sources, including other streams, Iterators, Iterables, Collections,
- you cannot "reset" a stream, that would be like "reprogramming the transformation". Resetting the data source is probably what you want.
- there is logically only 1 data item 'in flight' in the stream at any time (unless the stream is a parallel stream, at which point, there is 1 item per thread). This is independent of the data source which may have more than the current items 'ready' to be supplied to the stream, or the stream collector which  may need to aggregate and reduce multiple values.
- Streams can be unbound (infinite), limited only by the data source, or collector (which can be infinite too).
- Streams are 'chainable', the output of filtering one stream, is another stream. Values input to and transformed by a stream can in turn be supplied to another stream which does a different transformation. The data, in its transformed state flows from one stream to the next. You do not need to intervene and pull the data from one stream and plug it in to the next.

### C# Comparison

When you consider that a Java Stream is just a part of a supply, stream, and collect system, and that Streams and Iterators are often used together with Collections, then it is no wonder that it is hard to relate to the same concepts which are almost all embedded in to a single `IEnumerable` concept in C#.

Parts of IEnumerable (and close related concepts) are apparent in all of the Java Iterator, Iterable, Lambda, and Stream concepts.

There are small things that the Java concepts can do that are harder in IEnumerable, and visa-versa.

---

## Conclusion

- There's no design problem here, just a problem in matching concepts between the languages.
- Streams solve problems in a different way
- Streams add functionality to Java (they add a different way of doing things, they do not take functionality away)

Adding Streams gives you more choices when solving problems, which is fair to classify as 'enhancing power', not 'reducing', 'taking away', or 'restricting' it.

#### Why are Java Streams once-off?

This question is misguided, because streams are function sequences, not data. Depending on the data source that feeds the stream, you can reset the data source, and feed the same, or different stream.

#### Unlike C#'s IEnumerable, where an execution pipeline can be executed as many times as we want, in Java a stream can be 'iterated' only once.

Comparing an `IEnumerable` to a `Stream` is misguided. The context you are using to say `IEnumerable` can be executed as many times as you want, is best compared to Java `Iterables`, which can be iterated as many times as you want. A Java `Stream` represents a subset of the `IEnumerable` concept, and not the subset that supplies data, and thus cannot be 'rerun'.

#### Any call to a terminal operation closes the stream, rendering it unusable. This 'feature' takes away a lot of power.

The first statement is true, in a sense. The 'takes away power' statement is not. You are still comparing Streams it IEnumerables. The terminal operation in the stream is like a 'break' clause in a for loop. You are always free to have another stream, if you want, and if you can re-supply the data you need. Again, if you consider the `IEnumerable` to be more like an `Iterable`, for this statement, Java does it just fine.

#### I imagine the reason for this is not technical. What were the design considerations behind this strange restriction?

The reason is technical, and for the simple reason that a Stream a subset of what think it is. The stream subset does not control the data supply, so you should reset the supply, not the stream. In that context, it is not so strange.

#### QuickSort example

Your quicksort example has the signature:

```
IEnumerable<int> QuickSort(IEnumerable<int> ints)
```

You are treating the input `IEnumerable` as a data source:

```
IEnumerable<int> lt = ints.Where(i => i < pivot);
```

Additionally, return value is `IEnumerable` too, which is a supply of data, and since this is a Sort operation, the order of that supply is significant. If you consider the Java `Iterable` class to be the appropriate match for this, specifically the `List` specialization of `Iterable`, since List is a supply of data which has a guaranteed order or iteration, then the equivalent Java code to your code would be:

```
Stream<Integer> quickSort(List<Integer> ints) {
    // Using a stream to access the data, instead of the simpler ints.isEmpty()
    if (!ints.stream().findAny().isPresent()) {
        return Stream.of();
    }

    // treating the ints as a data collection, just like the C#
    final Integer pivot = ints.get(0);

    // Using streams to get the two partitions
    List<Integer> lt = ints.stream().filter(i -> i < pivot).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> gt = ints.stream().filter(i -> i > pivot).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return Stream.concat(Stream.concat(quickSort(lt), Stream.of(pivot)),quickSort(gt));
}
```

Note there is a bug (which I have reproduced), in that the sort does not handle duplicate values gracefully, it is a 'unique value' sort.

Also note how the Java code uses data source (`List`), and stream concepts at different point, and that in C# those two 'personalities' can be expressed in just `IEnumerable`. Also, although I have use `List` as the base type, I could have used the more general `Collection`, and with a small iterator-to-Stream conversion, I could have used the even more general `Iterable`

Comment: Then a Stream like a "limited IQueryable" (where iterating it is "evaluating the query")?

Comment: If you are thinking of 'iterating' a stream, you are doing it wrong. A stream represents the state of data at a particular point in time in a chain of transformations. Data enters the system in a stream source, then flows from one stream to the next, changing state as it goes, until it is collected, reduced, or dumped, at the end. A `Stream` is a point-in-time concept, not a 'loop operation'.... (cont.)

Comment: With a Stream, you have data entering the stream looking like X, and exiting the stream looking like Y. There is a function that the stream does that performs that transformation `f(x)` The stream encapsulates the function, it does not encapsulate the data that flows through

Comment: Great answer, but can we conclude there is no "loss of power" due to Java streams not being reusable like C# enumerables are? Conversely, is there something doable with streams which cannot be done with enumerables? C# enumerables don't provide for parallel aggregations, perhaps?

Comment: @Rogério: since the Java framework relaxes the requirements for the stream source, the options for constructing a stream would be the first thing to compare. Can you create a stream of random numbers or consisting of lines read from a network socket or from an arbitrary `Supplier` (which might supply a different value each time) in C#? Having a clear API that isn’t bloated with contradicting methods is also a “gain of power”, e.g. does calling `Reverse()` on a `List` modify the list or return a lazy `IEnumerable` like with other `IEnumerable`s…

Comment: `IEnumerable` can also supply random values, be unbound, and become active before the data exists.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm kind of surprised that it didn't mention the .NET `Stream` classes at all.  Some of those classes *do* support seeking.

Comment: @AndrewVermie - I'm a Java-person by default, and my C# knowledge does not compare. The question was tagged as Java.... so I intentionally did not go too many places where my knowledge is lacking. If you feel the answer can be improved though, feel free to edit.

Comment: @Arturo Torres Sánchez: so what means iterating multiple times for these kind of `IEnumerable`s then?

Comment: I think that C#'s IEnumerable is a perfect analogy for a stream. As was mentioned, it does not assume anything about a particular backing store, it can be infinite, it can provide data 'on the fly' and it support chainable execution pipelines. 

Java streams are a great tool. When I said that this feature 'reduces' their strength- I meant that it prevents them from achieving their full potential.

Comment: @Holger, for a random, you get different sequences every time. For an infinite, you need to stop somehow (e.g. using `.Take(20)` for the first 20 items), and for lazy data retrieval (such as Entity Framework), I believe the data is loaded and cached once, and then the next iterations will be faster.

Comment: @Vitaliy: Many methods that receive an `IEnumerable<T>` expect it to represent a finite collection which may be iterated multiple times.  Some things which are iterable but don't meet those conditions implement `IEnumerable<T>` because no other standard interface fits the bill, but methods that expect finite collections that can be iterated multiple times are prone to crash if given iterable things that don't abide by those conditions.

Comment: I reject that the comparison is misguided, there are too many similarities as not to compare. In your detailed description of stream traits, you can substitute the word stream by IEnumerable in all bullets but one- the tipic of the question. Java is not a mathematical language. Infinite streams and random streams are interesting examples, but it so happens that the vast majority of code using stream is backed by finite deterministic data structures.

Comment: @Vitaliy - I am sorry I have not been able to explain myself more clearly. I am not saying that IEnumerable and Stream classes are not comparable. They are comparable, clearly. But, you cannot find all of the IEnumerable concepts in just the Stream concept, but if you combine Stream, Iterator, and Iterables, then you will find almost all of IEnumerable. Streams only compares to a small subset of IEnumerable. Trying to compare Streams to all of IEnumerable is misguided. Comparing it to a part of IEnumerable is not misguided

Comment: Your `quickSort` example could be much simpler if it returned a `Stream`; it would save two `.stream()` calls and one `.collect(Collectors.toList())` call. If you then replace `Collections.singleton(pivot).stream()` with `Stream.of(pivot)` the code becomes almost readable…

Answer (score 22):

`Stream`s are built around `Spliterator`s which are stateful, mutable objects. They don’t have a “reset” action and in fact, requiring to support such rewind action would “take away much power”. How would [`Random.ints()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints--) be supposed to handle such a request?

On the other hand, for `Stream`s which have a retraceable origin, it is easy to construct an equivalent `Stream` to be used again. Just put the steps made to construct the `Stream` into a reusable method. Keep in mind that repeating these steps is not an expensive operation as all these steps are lazy operations; the actual work starts with the terminal operation and depending on the actual terminal operation entirely different code might get executed.

It would be up to you, the writer of such a method, to specify what calling the method twice implies: does it reproduce exactly the same sequence, as streams created for an unmodified array or collection do, or does it produce a stream with a similar semantics but different elements like a stream of random ints or a stream of console input lines, etc.

---

By the way, to avoid confusion, a terminal operation *consumes* the `Stream` which is distinct from *closing* the `Stream` as calling `close()` on the stream does (which is required for streams having associated resources like, e.g. produced by `Files.lines()`).

---

It seems that a lot of confusion stems from misguiding comparison of `IEnumerable` with `Stream`. An `IEnumerable` represents the ability to provide an actual `IEnumerator`, so its like an `Iterable` in Java. In contrast, a `Stream` is a kind of iterator and comparable to an `IEnumerator` so it’s wrong to claim that this kind of data type can be used multiple times in .NET, the support for `IEnumerator.Reset` is optional. The examples discussed here rather use the fact that an `IEnumerable` can be used to fetch *new* `IEnumerator`s and that works with Java’s `Collection`s  as well; you can get a new `Stream`. If the Java developers decided to add the `Stream` operations to `Iterable` directly, with intermediate operations returning another `Iterable`, it was really comparable and it could work the same way.

However, the developers decided against it and the decision is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24472312/2711488). The biggest point is the confusion about eager Collection operations and lazy Stream operations. By looking at the .NET API, I (yes, personally) find it justified. While it looks reasonable looking at `IEnumerable` alone, a particular Collection will have lots of methods manipulating the Collection directly and lots of methods returning a lazy `IEnumerable`, while the particular nature of a method isn’t always intuitively recognizable. The worst example I found (within the few minutes I looked at it) is [`List.Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b0axc2h2(v=vs.110).aspx) whose name matches *exactly* the name of the inherited (is this the right terminus for extension methods?) [`Enumerable.Reverse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb358497(v=vs.110).aspx) while having an entirely contradicting behavior.

---

Of course, these are two distinct decisions. The first one to make `Stream` a type distinct from `Iterable`/`Collection` and the second to make `Stream` a kind of one time iterator rather than another kind of iterable. But these decision were made together and it might be the case that separating these two decision never was considered. It wasn’t created with being comparable to .NET’s in mind.

The actual API design decision was to add an improved type of iterator, the `Spliterator`. `Spliterator`s can be provided by the old `Iterable`s (which is the way how these were retrofitted) or entirely new implementations. Then, `Stream` was added as a high-level front-end to the rather low level `Spliterator`s. That’s it. You may discuss about whether a different design would be better, but that’s not productive, it won’t change, given the way they are designed now.

There is another implementation aspect you have to consider. `Stream`s are *not* immutable data structures. Each intermediate operation may return a new `Stream` instance encapsulating the old one but it may also manipulate its own instance instead and return itself (that doesn’t preclude doing even both for the same operation). Commonly known examples are operations like `parallel` or `unordered` which do not add another step but manipulate the entire pipeline). Having such a mutable data structure and attempts to reuse (or even worse, using it multiple times at the same time) doesn’t play well…

---

For completeness, here is your quicksort example translated to the Java `Stream` API. It shows that it does not really “take away much power”.

```
static Stream<Integer> quickSort(Supplier<Stream<Integer>> ints) {

  final Optional<Integer> optPivot = ints.get().findAny();
  if(!optPivot.isPresent()) return Stream.empty();

  final int pivot = optPivot.get();

  Supplier<Stream<Integer>> lt = ()->ints.get().filter(i -> i < pivot);
  Supplier<Stream<Integer>> gt = ()->ints.get().filter(i -> i > pivot);

  return Stream.of(quickSort(lt), Stream.of(pivot), quickSort(gt)).flatMap(s->s);
}
```

It can be used like

```
List<Integer> l=new Random().ints(100, 0, 1000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(l);
System.out.println(quickSort(l::stream)
    .map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

You can write it even more compact as

```
static Stream<Integer> quickSort(Supplier<Stream<Integer>> ints) {
    return ints.get().findAny().map(pivot ->
         Stream.of(
                   quickSort(()->ints.get().filter(i -> i < pivot)),
                   Stream.of(pivot),
                   quickSort(()->ints.get().filter(i -> i > pivot)))
        .flatMap(s->s)).orElse(Stream.empty());
}
```

Comment: Well, consumes or not, trying to consume it again throws an exception that the stream was already *closed*, not consumed.

As to the problem with resetting a stream of random integers, as you said- it is up to the writer of the library to define the exact contract of a reset operation.

Comment: No, the message is “stream has *already been operated upon or* closed” and we weren’t talking about a “reset” operation but calling two or more terminal operations ona `Stream` whereas the resetting of the source `Spliterator`s would be implied. And I’m quite sure if that was possible, there were question on SO like “Why does calling `count()` twice on a `Stream` gives different results each time”, etc…

Comment: It is absolutely valid for count() to give different results. count() is a query on a stream, and if the stream is mutable (or to be more exact, the stream represents a result of a query on a mutable collection) then it is expected.

Have a look at C#'s API. They deal with all these issues gracefully.

Comment: What you call “absolutely valid” is a counter-intuitive behavior. After all, it’s the main motivation for asking about using a stream multiple times to process the result, expected to be the same, in different ways. Every question on SO about the non-reusable nature of `Stream`s so far stems from an attempt to solve a problem by calling terminal operations multiple times (obviously, otherwise you don’t notice) which led to a silently broken solution if the `Stream` API allowed it with different results on each evaluation. [Here is a nice example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23699178/2711488).

Comment: I disagree with your proposition that this always stems from broken solutions. I edited my question with an example.

Comment: Actually, your example perfectly demonstrates what happens if a programmer doesn’t understand the implications of applying multiple terminal operations. Just think about what happens when each of these operations will be applied to an entirely different set of elements. It only works if the stream’s source returned the same elements on each query but this is exactly the wrong assumption we were talking about.

Comment: > How would Random.ints() be supposed to handle such a request? <
It's perfectly doable to get an immutable lazy sequence of random elements, just have a look at Haskell Lists:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randoms

Answer (score 8):

I think there are very few differences between the two when you look closely enough.

At it's face, an `IEnumerable` does appear to be a reusable construct:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

foreach (var n in numbers) {
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

However, the compiler is actually doing a little bit of work to help us out; it generates the following code:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

IEnumerator<int> enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

Each time you would actually iterate over the enumerable, the compiler creates an enumerator.  The enumerator is not reusable; further calls to `MoveNext` will just return false, and there is no way to reset it to the beginning.  If you want to iterate over the numbers again, you will need to create another enumerator instance.

---

To better illustrate that the IEnumerable has (can have) the same 'feature' as a Java Stream, consider a enumerable whose source of the numbers is not a static collection.  For example, we can create an enumerable object which generates a sequence of 5 random numbers:

```
class Generator : IEnumerator<int> {
    Random _r;
    int _current;
    int _count = 0;

    public Generator(Random r) {
        _r = r;
    }

    public bool MoveNext() {
        _current= _r.Next();
        _count++;
        return _count <= 5;
    }

    public int Current {
        get { return _current; }
    }
 }

class RandomNumberStream : IEnumerable<int> {
    Random _r = new Random();
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
        return new Generator(_r);
    }
    public IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now we have very similar code to the previous array-based enumerable, but with a second iteration over `numbers`:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = new RandomNumberStream();

foreach (var n in numbers) {
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
foreach (var n in numbers) {
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

The second time we iterate over `numbers` we will get a different sequence of numbers, which isn't reusable in the same sense.  Or, we could have written the `RandomNumberStream` to thrown an exception if you try to iterate over it multiple times, making the enumerable actually unusable (like a Java Stream).

Also, what does your enumerable-based quick sort mean when applied to a `RandomNumberStream`?

---

### Conclusion

So, the biggest difference is that .NET allows you to reuse an `IEnumerable` by implicitly creating a new `IEnumerator` in the background whenever it would need to access elements in the sequence.

This implicit behavior is often useful (and 'powerful' as you state), because we can repeatedly iterate over a collection.

But sometimes, this implicit behavior can actually cause problems.  If your data source is not static, or is costly to access (like a database or web site), then a lot of assumptions about `IEnumerable` have to be discarded; reuse is not that straight-forward

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to bypass some of the "run once" protections in the Stream API; for example we can avoid `java.lang.IllegalStateException` exceptions (with message "stream has already been operated upon or closed") by referencing and reusing the `Spliterator` (rather than the `Stream` directly).

For example, this code will run without throwing an exception:

```
    Spliterator<String> split = Stream.of("hello","world")
                                      .map(s->"prefix-"+s)
                                      .spliterator();

    Stream<String> replayable1 = StreamSupport.stream(split,false);
    Stream<String> replayable2 = StreamSupport.stream(split,false);


    replayable1.forEach(System.out::println);
    replayable2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

However the output will be limited to

```
prefix-hello
prefix-world
```

rather than repeating the output twice. This is because the `ArraySpliterator` used as the `Stream` source is stateful and stores its current position. When we replay this `Stream` we start again at the end.

We have a number of options to solve this challenge:

1. We could make use of a stateless `Stream` creation method such as `Stream#generate()`. We would have to manage state externally in our own code and reset between `Stream` "replays":

   ```
   Spliterator<String> split = Stream.generate(this::nextValue)
                                     .map(s->"prefix-"+s)
                                     .spliterator();

   Stream<String> replayable1 = StreamSupport.stream(split,false);
   Stream<String> replayable2 = StreamSupport.stream(split,false);


   replayable1.forEach(System.out::println);
   this.resetCounter();
   replayable2.forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. Another (slightly better but not perfect) solution to this is to write our own `ArraySpliterator` (or similar `Stream` source) that includes some capacity to reset the current counter. If we were to use it to generate the `Stream` we could potentially replay them successfully.

   ```
   MyArraySpliterator<String> arraySplit = new MyArraySpliterator("hello","world");
   Spliterator<String> split = StreamSupport.stream(arraySplit,false)
                                           .map(s->"prefix-"+s)
                                           .spliterator();

   Stream<String> replayable1 = StreamSupport.stream(split,false);
   Stream<String> replayable2 = StreamSupport.stream(split,false);


   replayable1.forEach(System.out::println);
   arraySplit.reset();
   replayable2.forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
3. The best solution to this problem (in my opinion) is to make a new copy of any stateful `Spliterator`s used in the `Stream` pipeline when new operators are invoked on the `Stream`. This is more complex and involved to implement, but if you don't mind using third party libraries, [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) has a `Stream` implementation that does exactly this. (Disclosure: I am the lead developer for this project.)

   ```
   Stream<String> replayableStream = ReactiveSeq.of("hello","world")
                                                .map(s->"prefix-"+s);




   replayableStream.forEach(System.out::println);
   replayableStream.forEach(System.out::println);
   ```

This will print

```
prefix-hello
prefix-world
prefix-hello
prefix-world
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you can create streams from things that can only be used once by definition, such as an Iterator or a BufferedReader. You can think of a Stream as being consumed the same way as having used a BufferedReader to read a text file to its end. Once you reach the end of the file, the BufferedReader doesn't stop existing, but it just become useless as you can't get anything out of it anymore. If you want to read the file again, you have to create a new reader. The same goes for streams. If you want to process the source of the stream twice, you have to create two separate streams.