# Avoiding .stream() and .collect() when using lambdas with the old collection classes in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm just trying out lambdas in Java 8 and I'm quite disappointed because I cannot use them for instance on a plain `List`. Instead I always have to convert the `List` to a `Stream` and then convert back again via `.collect()`.

Is this the ways it's supposed to be or am I doing something wrong? Maybe the solution is to replace uses of the good old Collection with Stream where possible so .map and .filter can be used more naturally everywhere. However, I'm not sure whether this is considered good practice. Am I missing another trick to work around this problem?

Comment: See [here](http://www.lambdafaq.org/why-are-stream-operations-not-defined-directly-on-collection/). There's a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: You can still look at `Collection#removeIf` / `List#replaceAll` (with a mapping from `T` to `T`) if you wish to modify the list in place. You might be also interested by this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676877/should-i-return-a-collection-or-a-stream

Comment: No, you got it, using `stream()` and `collect()` is the intended way. If you want a more fluent API, go for an alternative collection library, such as [Goldman-Sachs Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/), [HPPC](https://github.com/vsonnier/hppcrt) etc., or just a more potent streaming library, like [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex).

Comment: It's all discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459498/why-are-java-streams-once-off).

Comment: Ok, thanks all. I think my question is answer with the combination of the Sotirios Delimanolis link and @Slanec's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` is defined directly on `List`. But for most operations, the expected use is something like:

```
convertedList = myList.stream().filter(...).map(...).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

so the conversion to and from a stream is pretty fluid.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I will just use more streams where appropriate.