# How to perform multiple (reusing) reductions/mapping/mixed operations from one Stream object

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

I understand that Java stream object doesn't allow `forked stream`. But it's also reasonable to imagine one would perform multiple actions to the same stream. Say I want to map a List of objects but also sum up a measurement across all objects. I'd like to know if it's possible to do so without dump data into a List.

```
Stream<Thing> thingStream = ...;
int accumulation = thingStream.mapToInt(Thing::measure).sum();
List<Another> results = thingStream.map(t -> toAnother(t)).collect(toList());
```

I know it's possible to use `Stream#peek` but it sounds hacky.

Comment: A `Stream` is a potentially infinite source of data. What makes you think you can consume it more than once? For example, I have a `Stream` of tempreature readings from a thermostat, they come in every millisecond.

Comment: From [the documentation of `java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html): "*Streams differ from collections in several ways: [...] Consumable. The elements of a stream are only visited once during the life of a stream. Like an Iterator, a new stream must be generated to revisit the same elements of the source.*" You are right, you could use `peek(...)` to do what you want, but it is hacky indeed. The documentation of `Stream#peek(...)` states that "*This method exists mainly to support debugging*". So no, what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call **only one** terminal operation (e.g: sum, count, collect .. ) on a stream, so the answer is no, you can not use the same stream to perform the 2 different terminal operations that you specified.

Small extract of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) says:

> After the
>   terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered
>   consumed, and can no longer be used; if you need to traverse the same
>   data source again, you must return to the data source to get a new
>   stream. In almost all cases, terminal operations are eager, completing
>   their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline
>   before returning. Only the terminal operations iterator() and
>   spliterator() are not; these are provided as an "escape hatch" to
>   enable arbitrary client-controlled pipeline traversals in the event
>   that the existing operations are not sufficient to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Each terminal operation calls iterator() up the chain to the source .You can call only one terminal operation because  Stream doesn't allow multiple traversal over its pipeline . Doing so will result in `IllegalStateException` .This has been chosen for consistency purpose to support one-shot stream sources like reading a file or  bytes from a network .

Please check  @StuartMarks answer in the below  link

[Why are Java Streams once-off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459498/why-are-java-streams-once-off/28513908#28513908)